# clearDataValidation() not working as I expected

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some code where I create a filtered dropdown list. So the A1 cell has a standard dropdown, and whatever I choose from there creates a filtered dropdown in the adjacent B1 cell. That all works well.

Before I create the validation rule, I clear out the B1 cell with

activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

This sort of works, as when I change the selection in A1, the adjacent cell clears, and the new filtered dropdown list appears. But if I press my keyboard delete button when the A1 cell is selected, so A1 is then blank, the adjacent column still creates a dropdown and says undefined.

So my code looks like this.

First, I clear everything.

activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

I follow this with

if (!activeCell.isBlank()) {

create the filtered dropdown in B1}

So I thought that as I was clearing the data validation first, the dropdown in B1 would appear only if A1 was NOT blank.

Answer (score 0):

More an apology than an answer. I went and had some lunch and came back added a Logger.log to check something and the code now works with no other modification.

Can't explain it. I've deleted the Logger.log, and it still works fine.

Comment: Haha, classic :)